Rename [manipulation] to [disassembly] (or similar)
The tag info for manipulation reads:

The technique of disassembling two or more parts from one another.

and all existing questions are actually about this.
However the word manipulation has a much broader scope than this, which is suboptimal for two reasons:

It may lead to people misusing the tag.
People who want to search questions about disassembling Lego cannot find them, as they cannot find the tag.

I therefore suggest to rename this tag to disassembly, dismantling, unbuilding, or deconstruction (and make the others synonyms).

I'm happy with the choice of [tag:disassembly] but [tag:dismantling] has a nice ring to it too.

Good call.
It seems like this is one of the relics of the early stages of the site. 
I've gone through all the questions (17) that use the [manipulation] and it seems to be that the [disassembly] tag is a better fit, so I have remapped the tag to the new one.
Three of these questions use the word 'disassemble' in some form in their title and the tag wiki already uses this word, so it seems more appropriate to use a word for that tag, rather than a word that nobody uses in that context.
